# Proca equation gauge conditions

Tags: field-theory, quantum-spin, bosons, degrees-of-freedom

In massive case without any gauge conditions proca equation can be written as

$\partial_\nu(\partial^\nu A^\mu- \partial^\mu A^\nu)+\left(\frac{mc}{\hbar}\right)^2 A^\mu=0$

Since $A_\mu$ is a $n$-vector (has $n$ components in $n$-dimensional spacetime) it must have 4 degrees of freedom in 4d spacetime. In other words, any spin-1 particle\that is described by Proca equation must have 4 spin states. But $Z$-boson and $W$-boson (since they're massive) have only 3 and photon has only 2

One degree of freedom can be cut with Lorenz gauge $$\partial_\mu A^\mu=0.$$

What are other constraints that cut another spin state for massless particles? How to derive those constraints (including Lorenz gauge as well)?

Comment: The Proca equation itself eliminates one degree of freedom, you can express $A_0$ as a function of $\vec{A}$.

Comment: If $m\neq 0$, the condition $\partial_\mu A^\mu=0$ is already embodied in the Proca equation. Just apply $\partial_\mu$ on both sides.  Therefore you have three degrees of freedom... As it must be since the partcle has spin $1$ and in its rest frame (it exists because $m\neq 0$) you see them as the three degrees of freedom of the spin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A gauge condition is imposed because the "symmetry" $A_\mu \to A_\mu + \partial_\mu \alpha$ describes a redundancy (for small $\alpha$) in our description of photons. We remove this redundancy by imposing a gauge condition. The Proca Lagrangian has no such symmetry (for $m^2 \neq 0$) so there is no concept of gauge condition for a massive spin-1 field.

The usual d.o.f. counting goes as follows. A vector field has 4 components. One of these is removed by EoM so we have 3 independent on-shell d.o.f. which is precisely the correct number for massive spin-1 fields. For massless fields, there is an additional gauge symmetry which we remove by imposing a separate gauge condition which reduces the number of physical on-shell d.o.f. from 4 to 2.